# How to put an image behind the curved header container in HTML?

Tags: html, css

[How can I achieve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0NzU.png)[image]

How can I put the image that I have behind the curved header? I already have the curved header but I just don't know how can I put the image on it.

[here is my current code on it](https://jsfiddle.net/rmallari/7305dmsb/1/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 0 0 60% 60%/ 0 0 50% 50%;
  border-bottom: #FF0000 20px solid;
}

section .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  text-align: left;
}

section .content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

section .content h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>WELCOME!</h2>
      <p>We know you want a job where you can perform at the highest level. </p>
      <p>That’s why we created the Global English Assessment, so you know how you can evolve your communication skills to increase your compensation and success at ePerformax.</p>
      <p>This assessment will give you a plan to be your best and meet your goals.</p>
      <p>Click Continue to get started.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve the actual image that I have, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the CSS z-index property to style some layer in your code.

For exaple, you can give to your curved header a bigger z-index than the one that you will give to your image (ot the element that has it as background, if it is the case): this will make your header pop over the image.

Here's  [some info about this property on the W3C school site](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I have added the image in container ..maybe span with class name image within section container and playing with position absolute  for image :

I have put the code example here

```css
  body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    section{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .image {
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 400px;
      -moz-border-radius: 400px;
      border-radius: 400px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index:5
    }
    .image img {
      border-radius:600px;
    }

    section:before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000;
      background: #333333;
      border-radius: 0 0 60% 60%/ 0 0 50% 50%;
      border-bottom: #FF0000 20px solid;
    }

    section .content{
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 900px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    section .content p{
      color:#fff;
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    section .content h2{
      color:#fff;
      font-size: 3em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Simple Login System in Laravel</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <section>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>WELCOME!</h2>
        <p>We know you want a job where you can perform at the highest level. </p>
        <p>That’s why we created the Global English Assessment, so you know how you can evolve your communication skills to increase your compensation and success at ePerformax.</p>
        <p>This assessment will give you a plan to be your best and meet your goals.</p>
        <p>Click Continue to get started.</p>
      </div>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="">
      </span>
    </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .header{
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9;
        top: 100px;
    }
    .header__overlay{
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
      background-color: green;
      top: -30px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .header__img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .header__content{
       position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      bottom: 203px;
      left: 0;
      padding: 21px;
      background-color: #ffffff6e;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header__overlay">
            <img class="header__img" src="https://myoffices.com/code/images/pictures/5.jpg"/>
            
            <div class="header__content">
                 <h2>WELCOME!</h2>
                 <p>
                   It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```